# How to save form data into AsyncStorage and then automatically send that data into mongodb when internet is connected

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to save the form submitted data into AsyncStorage and then automatically send that data into mongodb.

I have tried this. But it does not work. First time when i used the setItem it sets the item but now it is not setting the item.

I i put the code above the render then it gives me an error **too many renders**.

**code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { useNetInfo } from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


const App = () => {
    const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('');
    const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState('');
    const [data, setData] = React.useState('');
    const [synched, setSynched] = React.useState('');


    const netInfo = useNetInfo();


    const submit = () => {
        if (netInfo.isConnected) {
            var inputData = {
                "email": text,
                "password": number
            }

            const storeData = async () => {
                try {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem("Data", JSON.stringify(inputData))
                }
                catch (e) {
                    Alert.alert(e)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            var inputData = {
                "email": text,
                "password": number
            }
            const storeData = async () => {
                try {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem("Data", JSON.stringify(inputData))
                }
                catch (e) {
                    Alert.alert(e)
                }
            }
        }

    }



    if (netInfo.isConnected) {
        var networkConn = <Text style={{ color: "green" }}>Back Online</Text>
    }
    else {
        networkConn = <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>No internet</Text>
    }


    return (
        <View>
            <Modal
                animationType="slide"
                transparent={true}
                visible={modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                    Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                }}
            ></Modal>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Signup Form</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input1}
                onChangeText={onChangeText}
                placeholder="Enter your email"
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input1}
                onChangeText={onChangeNumber}
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
            />

            <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Button
                        style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'green' }}
                        styleDisabled={{ color: 'red' }}
                        onPress={submit}
                        title="Sign Up"
                    >
                    </Button>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View>
                <Text style={styles.text1}>{networkConn}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text1}>{synched}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text1}>{data}</Text>

            </View>

        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        marginTop: 50,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    text1: {
        marginTop: 10,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 12,
        color: 'black'
    },
    input1: {
        height: 40,
        marginLeft: 50,
        marginRight: 50,
        marginTop: 30,
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    btnContainer: {
        height: 100,
        marginTop: 30,
        width: 100,
        alignSelf: "center"
    },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting data in render is not good idea.
Well you can use this flow:

1. Store the data offline if internet is not available but with extra parameter like `isUploaded : false`
2. Then when internet is back get data from the storage check whether the data parameter i.e `isUploaded: false` if it is false then upload the data and if you wanna keep it then you can otherwise remove the item from the asyncstorage.